# How can I avoid that bower installs automatically packages I do not need?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, bower

I have installed angular-strap bower package.

angular-strap has no dependency to jquery or bootstrap just the bootstrap.css files not more.

When I do a bower update and all packages are updated then bower downloads and installs the:

bootstrap 3.2 package although I do not need that because I use a cdn for bootstrap 3.2 css files !!!

This is what I get after 'bower update':

```
C:\ipml>bower update
bower angular-touch#1.2.16      cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch.git#1.2.16
bower angular-touch#1.2.16    validate 1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch.git#1.2.16
bower angular-animate#1.2.16    cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.2.16
bower angular-animate#1.2.16  validate 1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.2.16
bower jquery#~2.1.1             cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.1
bower jquery#~2.1.1           validate 2.1.1 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~2.1.1
bower angular#~1.2.22           cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.22
bower angular#~1.2.22         validate 1.2.22 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.22
bower angular-strap#~2.0.5      cached git://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap.git#2.0.5
bower angular-strap#~2.0.5    validate 2.0.5 against git://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap.git#~2.0.5
bower angular-ui-router#~0.2.10 cached git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#0.2.10
bower angular-ui-router#~0.2.10         validate 0.2.10 against git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#~0.2.10
bower angular-mocks#1.2.16                cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.2.16
bower angular-mocks#1.2.16              validate 1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.2.16
bower angular-scenario#1.2.16             cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#1.2.16
bower angular-scenario#1.2.16           validate 1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#1.2.16
bower bootstrap#^3.2.0                    cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.2.0
bower bootstrap#^3.2.0                  validate 3.2.0 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#^3.2.0
bower angular-motion#^0.3.3               cached git://github.com/mgcrea/angular-motion.git#0.3.3
bower angular-motion#^0.3.3             validate 0.3.3 against git://github.com/mgcrea/angular-motion.git#^0.3.3
bower angular#1.2.16                      cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.16
bower angular#1.2.16                    validate 1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.16

Please note that,
    angular-animate#1.2.16, angular-mocks#1.2.16, angular-scenario#1.2.16, angular-touch#1.2.16 depends on angular#1.2.16 which resolved to angular#1.2.16
    ipml depends on angular#~1.2.22 which resolved to angular#1.2.22
    angular-ui-router#0.2.10 depends on angular#>= 1.0.8 which resolved to angular#1.2.22
    angular-strap#2.0.5 depends on angular#^1.2.21 which resolved to angular#1.2.22
    angular-motion#0.3.3 depends on angular#~1.2.10 which resolved to angular#1.2.22

Resort to using angular#~1.2.22 which resolved to angular#1.2.22
Code incompatibilities may occur.

bower bootstrap#^3.2.0                   install bootstrap#3.2.0

bootstrap#3.2.0 bower_components\bootstrap
└── jquery#2.1.1
```

The bad thing is when I do: 'bower uninstall bootstrap --save' then bootstrap is removed and when I do as next 'grunt build' I always get this message and can not continue anymore :/

```
Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Thats my bower file:

```
{
  "name": "ipml",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-animate": "1.2.16",
    "angular-touch": "1.2.16",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.10",
    "angular-strap": "~2.0.5",
    "angular": "~1.2.22"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.16",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.16"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.2.22"
  }
}
```

How can I remove bootstrap bower package without getting the "cannot read property 'main'..." message again which prevents me from building my code with grunt?

Comment: Why do you care? In the end, you decide what you put in in your html file, and thus what is actually downloaded by the browser. Also, it makes no sense to depend on angular 1.2.22 and to angular-animate 1.2.16. Use the same version number for all the angular dependencies.

Comment: I care because when a bower package is installed its automatically put inside my index.html between the bower script comments: <!-- bower.js -->. That does not make sense that angular and angular-animate should have the same version. That would mean nobody can use angular 1.2.22 together with angular-animate 1.2.16 as long there is no angular-animate 1.2.22 that would be stupid.

Comment: angular releases all its projects with the same versions at the same time. That makes sure angular, animate, route, mocks, cookies, etc. work well together.

Comment: Can you put this in a solution please! ;-)